# Performance of CSS grid place-items property vs margin property

Tags: html, css, css-grid

It's very easy to align all of your elements by just setting the parent div as `display: grid` and aligning the child elements with `place-items: center` but how does it compare to centering your elements with the `margin` property **`performance wise`**?

I'm finding myself putting `grid` on every parent, just to align items. Are there other downsides to using `grid` except that your parent has to be a `grid` element?